# tm document term matrix: processes wont terminate

Tags: r, tm

I am running the following on RStudio server on Ubuntu:

```
library(tm)
strings = sapply(1:1000, function(x){ paste(sample(c(letters[1:4], " "), 100, replace=T),   collapse="")})
corp = VCorpus(VectorSource(strings))
dtm = DocumentTermMatrix(corp)
```

It took me a few hours to realize DocumentTermMatrix was causing problems.  Each successive sourcing of my RStudio document (and same for command line etc) will create 2 more processes, e.g. I have 13 R processes now.  If i comment out the dtm line, I never see more processes created.

Could this be related to the recent-ish introduction of parallel somethingsomething in the tm package?  I was using .5 or so, and am now using .6, but am seeing the same behavior.

Just to be clear, this code *runs* fine.  The results come back correctly either way, but it's the lingering processes I'm concerned about.

Comment: That code works fine for me. I am using RStudio on MacOSX tm package version .6.

Comment: And by "works fine", you mean that no additional processes are created?

Comment: No, not that I can observe by investigating with top in terminal. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, though it might not show up in the top of "top".  These processes don't seem to be doing much besides consuming a little memory.  A `ps -ef | grep rstudio` will show them, or something slightly different if you used Rscript etc to run.  They got noticeable when I had 100 of them! :)

Comment: Gotcha! Yeah, nothing. just my active session. Sorry.

Comment: I had this problem when I was creating bigrams DTMs. I had to set `options(mc.cores=1)`. Everything worked well after that.

Comment: That works!  Kevin, if you post your comment as an answer I can accept it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer given by [Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144724/kevin) in the comments:

> set `options(mc.cores=1)`

A bit more details: `tm` package functions use parallelization. There are number of warnings for using it, refer the [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/html/mclapply.html). Sometimes it makes sense to use a single process by setting option `mc.cores=1`.

Note that different `tm` functions use different syntax for that, for example:

```
 tm_map(corp, stemDocument, mc.cores=1)
```

vs.

```
 DocumentTermMatrix(corp, options(mc.cores=1))
```